# I want to repeat a for loop that does an action for a set amount of times

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop, bots

My setup looks like this:

```
def WaitForObjects(self, type, string,):
    return WebDriverWait(self.browser,3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((type,string)))
```

Then i get all elements on a page with it and perform an action once per element:

```
that = self.WaitForObjects(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"class")
for this in that:             
    that.click()             
    time.sleep(this_time) 
         
    Action = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("path")             
    Action.click()             
    Action.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

my problem is that i want to stop after like 10 times the loop has run. How can i do that? (script itself works fine btw)

Comment: What about increasing a variable within the for loop and break the loop if the variable is `>= 10`?

Comment: What is `that`? Is it a `list`?

Comment: @Avinash yes, that is a list. It stands for all elements found by the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in your code.

```
for count, this in enumerate(that):
    if count == 10:
        break
    # Add your remaining code here
    # .....
    # .....
```

Comment: this solved it! Thank you very much!